# Error: Project need to deployed before you can started for remote debug and release in board

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app

I want to debug a windows universal app on a raspberry pi 2 board. But, when I click on "Remote Devices" to run the app on the raspberry pi 2, I get following error message on visual studio 2015 community RTM:

```
The project need to deployed before you can started
```

My app run on my host x86 plateform, but I can't run it on the remote device.

Answer (score 0):

i found a way for my question .

if you are use windows IOT for start on raspberry pi 2 you should download latest windows IOT from Microsoft site .

after download and install it try for install windows on your SD card for raspberry pi 2 and try again for run your app on it .

Answer (score 0):

When you get the following error 'The project need to deployed before you can started

[image: build error]

Is due to having the wrong setting in your remote debug options to check this simply right click on your project select properties check the debug options ensure your running debug ARM and have authentication set as Universal Unencrypted see

[image: IOTRemoteDebug]

Hope this helps anyone facing this issue